# Trouble with CreateNewSite() bindings -- WMI -- IIS6

Tags: arrays, binding, dns, iis-6, wmi

I am successfully creating new IIS 6 websites using the CreateNewSite() function, but would like to add an additional two hostname bindings (see below).

Questions:

1. Does the CreateNewSite() function support multiple hostname bindings?
2. If so, what is the syntax?  In all the example code I've found out there, I only find copies of the original MS code, with no examples of additional bindings, or even examples of modification functions.

I have already reviewed this blog page...

http://stweet.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-new-website-programmatically-on-iis-using-asp-net/

... and while I saw something that looked like multiple domains, the code format was different, and so I'm not sure how it relates to the VBS I am using.

Thanks,

Mik

---

`
    Bindings = Array(0)

```
Set Bindings(0) = providerObj.get("ServerBinding").SpawnInstance_() 
Bindings(0).IP = myIPnumber
Bindings(0).Port = "80" 
Bindings(0).Hostname = WScript.Arguments(0)


' Create the new Web site using the CreateNewSite method of the IIsWebService object. 
Dim strSiteObjPath 
strSiteObjPath = serviceObj.CreateNewSite("RF_" & WScript.Arguments(0), Bindings, "D:\websites\" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "\httpdocs", WScript.Arguments(2))
```

### `

The WScript.Arguments(2) is a custom IIS service number.

Comment: I just moved over to IIS7 and wow. The world just opened up didn't it.